# In the Endless, why don't people trapped in time loops just leave?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-endless

In the movie The Endless, we see both protagonists, Justin and Aaron, come and go between time loops and encounter people stuck within.

> And in the end, Justin and Aaron managed to runaway in a car.

Why don't these people just leave the way Justin and Aaron leave?

Answer (score 3):

It's been a while since I last watched the film, but I believe that you only become trapped in a loop if you are in the area of the loop at a certain point. Once you're trapped, you will keep repeating the loop and dying over and over, but if you aren't trapped then you aren't affected by the loops, and you can just leave.

I can't remember the exact trigger (I believe it had someting to do with the moon(s)) for being trapped, but Jason and Aaron do manage to leave in time to avoid being trapped.